# Should we use Option or ptr::null to represent a null pointer in Rust?

Tags: null, rust, idioms

The standard library's linked-list `Node` [uses the `Option` type](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.31.1/src/liballoc/collections/linked_list.rs#L52-L56):

```
struct Node<T> {
    next: Option<NonNull<Node<T>>>,
    prev: Option<NonNull<Node<T>>>,
    element: T,
}
```

and creates a node with this code:

```
Node {
    next: None,
    prev: None,
    element,
}
```

The implementation of `LeafNode` of `BTree`, the standard library [uses a raw pointer for the parent node](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.31.1/src/liballoc/collections/btree/node.rs#L65-L85):

```
struct LeafNode<K, V> {
    parent: *const InternalNode<K, V>,
    parent_idx: MaybeUninit<u16>,
    len: u16,
    keys: MaybeUninit<[K; CAPACITY]>,
    vals: MaybeUninit<[V; CAPACITY]>,
}
```

and creates new leaf nodes [by setting `parent` to `ptr::null`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.31.1/src/liballoc/collections/btree/node.rs#L91-L99):

```
LeafNode {
    keys: MaybeUninit::uninitialized(),
    vals: MaybeUninit::uninitialized(),
    parent: ptr::null(),
    parent_idx: MaybeUninit::uninitialized(),
    len: 0
}
```

We can use `nullptr` to implement the above code in C++, so what's the difference between `Option` and `std::ptr::null()` to represent a null pointer? What's the recommended way to represent a null pointer?

Comment: Are you asking for the difference between using `Option<NonNull<T>>` and `*mut T`?

Comment: @E_net4wisheshappyholidays I mean, what's the difference between Option and std::ptr::null() to implement nullptr, which way is recommended to implement nullptr?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general, I'd recommend using `NonNull<T>` over `*const T` or `*mut T`, using `Option` as appropriate to identify when the pointer may be null.

The reason is two-fold:

1. Whether null is a valid value, or not, is documented and *enforced* when using `NonNull`.
2. `*const T` and `*mut T` are essentially interchangeable, and indeed can be cast to one another, so that `const` or `mut` may provide a false sense of safety.

---

The implementation of `BTree` may simply not have been ported over to `NonNull`, which is relatively recent -- it was stabilized only in 1.25.

Comment: The NonNull documentation says: "If you're not sure if you should use NonNull<T>, just use *mut T!"