# How to check if a Box is a null pointer?

Tags: pointers, rust, null, box

I want to implement a stack using pointers or something. How can I check if a `Box` is a null pointer? I seen some code with `Option<Box<T>>` and `Box<Option<T>>` but I don't understand this. This is as far as I went:

```rust
struct Node {
    value: i32,
    next: Box<Node>,
}

struct Stack {
    top: Box<Node>,
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Box<T>` can never be NULL, therefore there is nothing to check.

> `Box<T>` values will always be fully aligned, non-null pointers
>
> — [`std::box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/index.html)

You most likely wish to use [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) to denote the absence / presence of a value:

```rust
struct Node {
    value: i32,
    next: Option<Box<Node>>,
}

struct Stack {
    top: Option<Box<Node>>,
}
```

See also:

- [Should we use Option or ptr::null to represent a null pointer in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54195517/155423)
- [How to set a field in a struct with an empty value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57962168/155423)
- [What is the null pointer optimization in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46557608/155423)

Answer (score 7):

You don't want `null`. `null` is an unsafe antipattern even in languages where you *have* to use it, and thankfully Rust rids us of the atrocity. `Box<T>` *always* contains a `T`, *never* `null`. Rust has no concept of `null`.

As you've correctly pointed out, if you want a value to be optional, you use `Option<T>`. Whether you do `Box<Option<T>>` or `Option<Box<T>>` really doesn't matter that much, and someone who knows a bit more about the lower-level side of things can chime in on which is more efficient.

```rust
struct Node {
    value: i32,
    next: Option<Box<Node>>,
}

struct Stack {
    top: Option<Box<Node>>,
}
```

The `Option` says "this may or may not exist" and the `Box` says "this value is on the heap. Now, the nice thing about `Option` that makes it infinitely better than `null` is that you *have* to check it. You *can't* forget or the compiler will complain. The typical way to do so is with `match`

```rust
match my_stack.top {
    None => {
        // Top of stack is not present
    }
    Some(x) => {
        // Top of stack exists, and its value is x of type Box<T>
    }
}
```

There are [tons of helper methods](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) on the `Option` type itself to deal with common patterns. Below are just a few of the most common ones I use. Note that *all* of these can be implemented in terms of `match` and are just convenience functions.

The equivalent of the following Java code

```java
if (value == null) {
  result = null;
} else {
  result = ...;
}
```

is

```rust
let result = value.map(|v| ...)
```

Or, if the inner computation can feasibly produce `None` as well,

```
let result = value.and_then(|v| ...)
```

If you want to provide a default value, say zero, like

```java
if (value == null) {
  result = 0;
} else {
  result = value;
}
```

Then you want

```rust
result = value.unwrap_or(0)
```

It's probably best to stop thinking in terms of how you would handle `null` and start learning `Option<T>` from scratch. Once you get the hang of it, it'll feel ten times safer and more ergonomic than `null` checks.

Comment: That's not appropriate for _this_ question, especially considering you've already asked it in [How do I implement a heap-based stack using Option<Box<T>>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66972893/155423)

Comment: In all honesty, and I mean this sincerely, based on this question and the one Shepmaster linked, my best advice to you is to slow down and read a good Rust tutorial. It seems like you're expecting Rust to be "C++ with funny syntax", but it's really not. It's an entirely different abstraction scheme, and the borrow checker has no real equivalent in any other mainstream language. Approach it like an entirely new paradigm. It'll do wonders.

Comment: Re ordering, prefer `Option<Box<T>>`. Done the other way you're dynamically allocating just so you can say you have nothing. Since Box is never null, `Option<Box<T>>` will use the null pointer bit pattern to store `None` for the option, for free.

Comment: "Rust has no concept of null." `std::ptr::null`?

Answer (score 2):

A `Box<T>` is a pointer to some location on the heap that contains some data of type `T`. Rust guarantees that `Box<T>` will never be a null pointer, i.e the address should always be valid as long as you aren't doing anything weird and `unsafe`.

If you need to represent a value that might not be there (e.g this node is the last node, so there is no `next` node), you can use the `Option` type like so

```rs
struct Node {
    value: i32,
    next: Option<Box<Node>>,
}

struct Stack {
    top: Option<Box<Node>>,
}
```

Now, with `Option<Box<Node>>`, `Node` can either have a next `Node` or no next node. We can check if the `Option` is not `None` like so

```rs
fn print_next_node_value(node: &Node) {
    match &node.next {
        Some(next) => println!("the next value is {}", next.value),
        None => println!("there is no next node")
    }
}
```

Because a `Box` is just a pointer to some location on the heap, it can be better to use `Option<Box<T>>` instead of `Box<Option<T>>`. This is because the second one will allocate an `Option<T>` on the heap, while the first one will not. Additionally, `Option<Box<T>>` and `Box<T>` are equally big (both are 8 bytes). This is because Rust knows that `Box<T>` can never be all zeros (i.e can never be the null pointer), so it can use the all-0's state to represent the `None` case of `Option<Box<T>>`.

Comment: Nitpick: Even if you *are* doing something weird and `unsafe`, `Box<T>` *still* isn't allowed to be a null pointer, any more than `true` is allowed to be `false`. If you write code that attempts to create a null `Box`, the behavior is undefined, and anything can happen: including the `Box` actually *not* being null. So `unsafe` isn't really an exception to the rule so much as an additional constraint.